# Noun+Adjective; as, ... ... blood-red, skin-deep, sky-blue,

Tags: grammar, punctuation

> Noun+Adjective; as, ... ... blood-red, skin-deep, sky-blue,

In the above, why is the comma used after *as* and what does *as* mean here?
And why is a semicolon used after title?

The extract (*slightly* amended) is from from *High School Grammar and Composition* by Wren & Martin.

Comment: It's just showing an abstraction (NOUN+ADJECTIVE), followed by particular examples. I think it would be more common to see "as in", rather than just "as" before enumerating the examples.

Comment: "Blood-blue" is an odd example - I don't think I've heard the term before. ("Blue blood", on the other hand, is well-known.)

Comment: Just a (non-standard) way of formatting complex bulletting. The semicolon here could be a big bullet and the comma a smaller bullet (but then we get to the actual list of examples ... and there have already been a section title (Compound Words) and subtitle (Compound Adjectives). You can see that they're struggling. //  'as' could equally be 'eg'.

Comment: They unhelpfully omit the open class of compounds. _Ink well_ is a compound noun different only in spelling from _ink-well_ and the now more common spelling _inkwell_. Likewise, the lexemes _particle board_, _particle-board_ and _particleboard_ are all compound nouns, merely the open, hyphenated and solid spelling variants.

Comment: Please provide an *actual* quotation and more context. What's given here makes little sense.

Comment: "Noun+Adjective; as, ... ... blood-red, skin-deep, sky-blue…" is no example of useful style but there's no clue whether the failing is original, or introduced by your amendment. As Edwin suggests, "as" could be "for example" or "that is to say."

The real issue is that "Noun+Adjective" is only part of the description. What seems to be under discussion is rather "Noun+Adjective=more specific adjective", which is to say adjectival hyphenation.

"Red" and "blue" describe colours. "Blood-red" and "sky-blue" change what were nouns into components of more specific, compound adjectives